# Use CURL Command to download remote files in Shell scripting

Tags: shell, curl, assembla

I need to download remote files using curl command below

```
curl -O -J "URL"
```

This is working as expected when I use this command separately when I try to use the same command in a shell script(below). it gives error below.

```
#!/bin/bash 
$curl -O -J "$url_final"
=======================================================
"curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"
```

Comment: What's your `$url_final`, and is `$curl` a typo ?

Comment: url_final is a variable which will download files. 
Curl is not a typo, it is working as a separate command in the terminal.

Comment: where `$url_final` is defined inside the script ? I am talking about the `$` sign in front of  `curl` inside the script, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a valid url in my tests seemed to have no issues with this curl request. I also tried using with and without wrapping the url in a string like you are along with using brackets.

```
url="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be"

# all work fine
curl -O -J $url 
curl -O -J "$url"
curl -O -J "{$url}"
```

My best answer is that your $url_final variable is undefined, empty, or malformed.

Comment: I feel the problem is the URL which I am generating. I have to revisit the URL again.